# Initialize query variable in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

How can I assign a default value (except `null`) to `Query` type in *Hibernate*?

For e.g. in case of list we assign like this:

```
List<DTO> obj =new ArrayList<DTO>();
```

Currently I directly assign query statement to the variable like this:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from foo Foo as foo where foo.name=:name and foo.size=:size");
```

Comment: Could you please better explain your requirement?
Do you intend to have default `Query` return result?

Answer (score 0):

I think so the problem is your query, don't make a sense have a "default" value for the "Query".

Try change your query to:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Foo f where f.name = :name and f.size = :size");
```